# Firebase get by date and order by voteCount

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a question about sorting. I want to get the first 10 posts added today, this week, and this month (So I have 30 posts total but each 10 posts from a different part of the database). This works perfect but the problem is that I want to sort all of them by `voteCount`'.

Is there any way to sort them by `date` and `voteCount`?

My reference:

```
const ref = firebase.database().ref('bookmarks')
    .orderByChild('date')
    .startAt(date.end)
    .endAt(date.start)
    .limitToLast(10)
```

Comment: There can be only one `orderBy` call in a Firebase query. Sometimes you can combine the values into a single property. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

f you're willing to pad-print the numbers into a string like this you can sort on basically anything:

```
"sortKey": "9899999-8521969121365-000009692795"
```

Don't forget Firebase can't sort-descending so you have to deal with that yourself. That's why my sortKey first field is 9899999. The value was actually 100000 but that portion is a descending sort so I'm subtracting it from 9999999.

Also don't forget to add an indexOn in your rules to avoid client-side sorting!

Comment: Firebase can sort descending. Kind of. Use negative values. To accomplish it, just keep a positive value in a node for ascending and a negative for descending. Query by the pos node for ascending and the neg node for descending. :-)

Comment: Right, that's what I'm doing above, subtracting the key value from a base. The important thing is just to know that composite keys end up being strings. In my example above I have such a key, so the trick to still alpha-sort but in descending order is to subtract from a large base, like 999999999. If your keys are simple numerics, you can subtract from 0 (make the number negative, as you noted).